# How to "materialize" Ionide function signature type hints as comments?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ionide

For example, given this function head, this is the hint that is generated:

```ml
let updateCell workbook sheetIndex rowIndex columnIndex value =
// XSSFWorkbook -> int -> int -> int -> string -> unit
```

Helpful, but this hint cannot be saved with the source code, and it also cannot be copied by selecting it (I had to type it in here). I could use explicit typing, but the readability is worse:

```ml
let updateCell (workbook: XSSFWorkbook) (sheetIndex: int) (rowIndex: int) (columnIndex: int) (value: string) =
```